# Video Colors Washed Out On Export

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, color, color-management

Export png sequences. Composite them together in new Blender file with audio.

[image]

Export as FF-MPEG H.264. Colors come out all washed out and yellow in all media players.

Import exported video file back into Blender and it looks fine, it only looks right when imported into Blender.

RIGHT Windows Media Player LEFT Blender (Same exact exported MP4 video)
[image]

[Video File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ki_1assq9RRXX8yz7qeLPYyH7ZWY73wT/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Very likely GPU / CPU / decoding software. Duplicate questions here with more information.

Answer (score 3):

In the render settings, try to change View Transform from Filmic to Standard:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and every other color management combination and nothing works. Still yellowish.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was able to improve the color by changing the Encoding Speed from Good to Slowest. Output Properties -> Output -> Video -> Encoding Speed